# It is possible to have a horizontal scrolling bar on the AnyChart tables?

Tags: scroll, anychart

I've reached an issue where there are too many columns of data in this table and I'd like it to continue on the graphic with the option for the user to scroll horizontally. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the orientation() method. You can re-position the scroll bar using it.

```
// change the scroller orientation
chart.xScroller().orientation("top");
chart.yScroller().orientation("left");
```

To adjust scroll bar height (width) use the height() method. There are also maxHeight() and minHeight() methods which are useful when your charts are being resized.

```
// set the bar height
chart.xScroller().maxHeight(35);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done only with CSS. Below you can find the approach how to enable scrolling for the AnyChart table with CSS.

```js
anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {

        var stage = null;

        //array for common padding settings
        var padding = [0, 10, 0, 10];

        //initial create table
        createTable();
        
                        //create table with headers
        stageHeaders = anychart.graphics.create("headers");
    //create standalone table
    tableHeaders = anychart.standalones.table();
    var headers = [];
    headers.push(['Static header', 'static header']);
        tableHeaders.contents(headers);
        tableHeaders.getCol(0).width(100);
        tableHeaders.container(stageHeaders).draw();
        
                stageBottom = anychart.graphics.create("bottom");
    //create standalone table
    tableBot = anychart.standalones.table();
                        var axes = [];
    axes.push(['Static bottom', 'Static bottom']);
        tableBot.contents(axes);
        tableBot.getCol(0).width(100);
        tableBot.container(stageBottom).draw();
       
        //create table
        function createTable() {
            if (stage !== null) {
                stage.dispose();
            }

            stage = anychart.graphics.create("container");

            //create standalone table
            table = anychart.standalones.table();

            var tableContent = [];
            tableContent.push(['Content', 'Content']);

            for (var j = 0; j<20; j++) {
                    tableContent.push(['Content', 'Content']);
            }

            tableContent.push(['THE END', null]);

            table.contents(tableContent);

                //adjust table appearance
                table.getRow(0).height(45);

                for (var k=0; k<table.rowsCount(); k++) {
                    table.getRow(k).height(45);
                }

                table.getCol(0).width(100);
                table.getCol(0).border().left('white');
                table.getCol(0).border().top('white');
                table.getCol(0).border().bottom('white');
                table.getCol(1).border().right('white');
                table.getCol(1).border().top('white');
                table.getCol(1).border().bottom('white');
                table.getCol(1).cellPadding(padding);
                table.vAlign('middle');

            //render the table
            table.container(stage).draw();
      stage.height(1000);
        }
    });
```

```css
html, body {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        #container {
            position: relative;
            width: 95%;
            height: 65%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow-y: scroll;
        }
                #headers {
            position: relative;
            width: 95%;
            height: 10%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
                        #bottom {
            position: relative;
            width: 95%;
            height: 10%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
```

```html
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.0.1/js/anychart-base.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.0.1/js/anychart-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.0.1/js/anychart-exports.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.0.1/js/anychart-bullet.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.0.1/js/anychart-table.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.0.1/css/anychart-ui.min.css"/>
    
<div id="headers"></div>
<div id="container"></div>
<div id="bottom"></div>
```